# Yarn install failed with "403 Forbidden" error, when running behind corporate proxy

Tags: maven, proxy, yarnpkg

When running yarn install through maven-front-end plugin behind a corporate proxy, the installation is failing at goal "yarn" with the following error:

> [ERROR] error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular/forms/-/forms-4.4.3.tgz:
>   Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"".

The appropriate section of the pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and yarn</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
              <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>yarn set proxy config</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>config set strict-ssl false -g</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>              
          <execution>
            <id>yarn install</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>yarn</goal> --- Fails here
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Can anyone please point out what may be the issue ? Here is the log:

> [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ plmapp-web2
>
> [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-yarn (install
>   node and yarn) @ plmapp-web2 ---
>
> [INFO] Found proxies: [optional{protocol='http', host='proxy',
>   port=8080}, optional_https{protocol='https', host='proxy', port=8080}]
>
> [INFO] Node v6.11.3 is already installed.  [INFO] Yarn 1.1.0 is
>   already installed.
>
> [INFO] Found proxies: [optional{protocol='http', host='proxy',
>   port=8080}, optional_https{protocol='https', host='proxy', port=8080}]
>
> [INFO] Running 'yarn config set strict-ssl false -g
>   --https-proxy=http://proxy:8080 --proxy=http://proxy:8080' in /tmp/plm/build-dir/PWA-PWA-JOB1/plmapp-web2
>
> [INFO] yarn config v1.1.0
>
> [INFO] success Set "strict-ssl" to "false". [INFO] Done in 0.09s.
>
> [INFO]    [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) @
>   plmapp-web2 ---
>
> [INFO] Found proxies: [optional{protocol='http', host='proxy',
>   port=8080}, optional_https{protocol='https', host='proxy', port=8080}]
>
> [INFO] Running 'yarn
>   --https-proxy=http://proxy:8080 --proxy=http://proxy:8080' in /tmp/plm/build-dir/PWA-PWA-JOB1/plmapp-web2
>
> [INFO] yarn install v1.1.0
>
> [INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
>
> [INFO] [2/4] Fetching packages...
>
> [INFO] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with
>   the information provided in
>   "/tmp/plm/build-dir/PWA-PWA-JOB1/plmapp-web2/yarn-error.log".
>
> [INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for
>   documentation about this command.
>
> [ERROR] error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular/forms/-/forms-4.4.3.tgz:
>   Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"".

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this problem?